# Ruby variable scopes

Tags: ruby

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Person
  attr_reader :short_name
  def initialize(short_name)
    @short_name = short_name
  end

  def greeting_line
    short_name = short_name.downcase
    "Hello #{short_name}"
  end
end

person = Person.new("MS. LEE")

puts person.short_name  => "MS. LEE"
puts person.greeting_line => NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

The exception occurs at "short_name = short_name.downcase" since (short_name = short_name) makes short_name become nil.

Why is "short_name" on the right side is not getting the value from the instance method "short_name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
var = value
```

it **always** refers to the local variable `var`, even if you have the methods `var` and `var=` defined. (In your case, you have the method `short_name` defined by `attr_reader`, but you don't have `short_name=` defined.)

You have a couple ways around this.  You can use the instance variable directly:

```
@var = value
```

Or you can use the `var=` method with an explicit `self` receiver:

```
self.var = value
```

This second form only works if you have a `var=` method defined, either explicitly, or with `attr_accessor` or `attr_writer`.

Now, when you do something like

```
foo = foo
```

This **always** introduces a local variable, `foo` on the left hand side.  When ruby sees `foo` on the right hand side of the `=`, it resolves to the *local variable* `foo`, since `foo` is now in scope.  So this always just sets `foo` back to its default value, `nil`.

Comment: the "short_name" (on the left side) in the "greeting_line" is intended to be a local variable. The "short_name.downcase" (on the right side) in intended to be the value.

Comment: However, one of the reason I wrote it that way was to leave the instance variable unchange.  If I use @short_name = ....  this will change it.

Comment: It was intended not to have `short_name=` being defined, so the `short_name =` in the `greeting_line` should be a local variable--as intended.

Comment: @user608800 Once the local variable `short_name` is in scope, then using `short_name` is always treated as the local variable.  It comes into scope from the left hand side of the `=`, and is then in scope in the right hand side (with its default value of `nil`.

Comment: Chris, would you please put it as an answer instead of a comment so others could vote on it.  Also, if you could provide a reference/link to prove your conclusion is not coming from your own observation then it would be great.

Comment: @user608800 (keeping me honest...) http://wiki.ruby-standard.org/wiki/Scope_of_variables section 9.1.2.

Comment: In other words, there are 2 local variables.  "short_name" on the left is a local variable. "short_name" on the right is another local variable (should be different memory allocation, right?), and not the instance method "short_name" (since "short_name" is already in scope.)  Thank you @ChrisRice

Comment: @user608800 No, there is still only one local variable, which you introduced on the left of the `=`, and you refer to the same variable on the right side of the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case in `greeting_line` scope short_name is pointing to local variable and not to instance method `short_name`, for this example to work you should use `self.short_name` (this will tell ruby to use instance method)

```
def greeting_line
 short_name = self.short_name.downcase
 "Hello #{short_name}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  I guess Ruby is always parsing the left side of the "=" first.  And this cause the "short_name" on the right side point the the local variable "short_name" instead of the instance method "short_name"?

Comment: My previous comment doesn't make sense either.  What happen if I have n = 0; n = n + 1.  The n on the right side is obviously NOT looking at the n on the left side.

Comment: Nonetheless, I like this answer because `self.short_name.downcase` gives a hint of avoiding ambiguous.  But it fails on answering WHY my code was ambiguous.

Comment: When you use `=` operator ruby tries to find `var=` method, then it looks for variable `var` if not present it will define it and assign it to result of right side of expresion. In your case at the moment right side is executed, `short_name` in current scope is local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot the @ when referencing short_name

```
@short_name
```

is an instance variable

```
short_name
```

is a local variable bound to the scope of the greeting_line function

Try this:

```
def greeting_line
  short_name = @short_name.downcase
  "Hello #{short_name}"
end
```

Comment: All these short_names... maybe just `"Hello #{@short_name.downcase}"`.

Comment: You mean "Hello #{@short_name.downcase}"

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I know @short_name.downcase would work.  However, I am more interested on the variable scopes.

Comment: ie: "short_name" on the left side should be a local variable to the method greeting_line; in contrary, "short_name.downcase" on the right side is not.  This "short_name" should be a method I declared earlier using "attr_reader :short_name"

Comment: To elaborate my point, if I change the line to "n = short_name.downcase" and "Hello #{n}", it would work too.  This is why I choose the title "Ruby variable scopes" because I can't explain to myself why "short_name = short_name.downcase" doesn't work.

Comment: I know how to make "greeting_line" work as it was intended; however, it was not the reason why I post it here.  I want to know why this is not working. (for details, see my comments before).  Thank you.

Comment: To Luke:
Thank you and I see you are answering my question in the right direction. But I fail to see why it is ambiguous.  Since there is no "def short_name=(s)" or "attr_writer :short_name" being defined, then "short_name = short_name.downcase", the "short_name on the left side should be treated as a local variable, isn't it?

Comment: Ya I see your point now. You asked a really good question, not sure what to say. Whats odd is that even if you add attr_accessor :short_name the function still doesn't work unless you change it to self.short_name = self.short_name.downcase, which I don't think is the behavior you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
  attr_accessor :short_name
```

And not attr_reader.

attr_reader produces the following method in your class:

```
def short_name
  @short_name
end
```

attr_accessor will also produce the method:

```
def short_name=(val)
  @short_name = val
end
```

Which will allow you to freely set the short_name as it was a local variable.

This is a [nice blog post](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) that demonstrates attr_reader, attr_writer and attr_accessor statements in ruby.

Comment: depends on if you want to be able to write to that variable as well as read from it

Comment: I believe you must use `self.short_name=(val)` for this to work.  Otherwise, Ruby will still treat `short_name` as a local variable.